# iOS Swift autocomplete dropdown with also own keywords

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I'm looking for a way to create a textfield with autocomplete and dropdown feature so that a user can also add a new keyword.

Similar to this JS-selector:

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags

[image: dropdown own key]

[image: dropdown autocomplete]

The only difference is that my textfield should only accept one selection and no multiselect.

I've googled for open source or a payed widget for this, but mostly I found very old and not good looking stuff with Swift 1 and things like that.

So is there no fancy autocomplete-dropdown textfield which is simple to implement in my project?

Or is there a reason why there is so less stuff on a UI-object like the one I described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no auto-complete widget, that I'm aware of at least.

But you can create your own:

1. pull the string from the input textfield.
2. compare it against an array of potential keywords
3. pull the range of the string, highlight the letters in the keywords
4. where the user completes without selecting a drop down, add keyword

Comment: I know how it should work but my problem is with the implementation of this. Especially the UI functions

Comment: what part are you stuck on? if you show your code, I'll try to help.

Comment: I've posted a related question here. Also there is a link to my repository where I've uploaded the code. Thanks for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923986/creating-a-custom-uitextfield-component-with-autocomplete-and-dropdown-features

Answer (score 2):

Check this https://github.com/mnbayan/AutocompleteTextfieldSwift.
Really easy to use and implement. You just need to create the UITextField as this type and set the content to check.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a simple auto-complete pop up view named [SwiftAutoSuggestion](https://github.com/RevanthKausikan/SwiftAutoSuggestion)

Add `pod 'SwiftAutoSuggestion'` in your pod file

Then, Run `pod install`.

More details an be found on the link.

Answer (score 0):

And, just to add another stick onto the woodpile, I just released [this (RVS_AutofillTextField)](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_AutofillTextField).

It's [a UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) that has been extended to provide a "dropdown" table, that acts as an autocomplete source.