# Creating a custom UITextField component with autocomplete and dropdown features

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, dropdownbox

I've created a Swift based sample application with a custom textfield and autocomplete and dropdown features.

Here is my sample app repository:
https://github.com/kingalione/autocomplete-dropdown

My goal is to create a iOS Swift based custom textfield component so I can reuse this component in my main application but my iOS experience is not that good to build this component at my own.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pod - https://github.com/jriosdev/iOSDropDown. You can even create your own custom drop-down but that might require a lot of time, better to use a cocoa library and get the work done within no time.

I hope this helps you.